# template registration error for push notification using fcm and azure in ionic app

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am developing a mobile app and adding push notification feature using fcm, azure notification hub. I created project in google firebase console and got sender id and Server key. Then configured my server key in azure portal push notification hub and installed push notification plugin in app with sender id. When i run my app i am getting push registration id but getting error in mobileServiceClient.push.register('gcm', handle, template).done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure) and unable to register my template.

Code is:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {  mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('url', 'server key');

pushNotification = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "*********"
            }
        });

        pushNotification.on('notification', function(data) {
            console.log(data.additionalData.docID);
        });

pushNotification.on('registration', function(data) {
            var platform = device.platform;
            var handle = data.registrationId;

            if (platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android') {
                var template = "{ \"data\" : {\"title\":\"$(title)\",\"message\":\"$(message)\",\"image\":\"$(image)\",\"channels\":\"$(channels)\",\"docID\":\"$(docID)\",\"additionalData\":\"$(additionalData)\"}}"
                $rootScope.mobileServiceClient.push.register('gcm', handle, template).done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
            }
        });
                var registrationSuccess = function() {
            $rootScope.ShowToast("Registered with Server!", false);
        }
        var registrationFailure = function(error) {  
            console.log('Failed registering with Server: ' + error); // error is coming here
        } }
```

Error:

Failed registering with Server: Error:

Comment: Error is: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server

Comment: What backend language are you using (C# or Node.js?)?

Comment: node.js language

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) can help you troubleshoot 502 error.